# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error when using removeObjectAtIndex in UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm fairly new to ios app development and I encountered this while trying to delete a row from cell:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef12743830'
```

here's my code:

header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *titles;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *animeNames;
@end
```

in `viewDidLoad` method i have this code that sets the values of `self.titles` and im getting row data from a `plist` file

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"animes" withExtension:@"plist"];
    self.animeNames = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.titles = self.animeNames.allKeys;
```

implementation file

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the row from the data source

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        NSMutableArray *current = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [current removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [tableView reloadData];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }

}
```

Comment: Although you call it an array, it appears that `current` is actually a string.  Should you be using `[self.titles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` instead?

Comment: @PhillipMills See my edit. adding this `[self.titles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` is having a `NSArray may not respond to removeObjectAtIndex` error

Comment: `NSArray` is immutable. You need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: As @rmaddy says, `titles` should be declared as a mutable array and you also need to make sure that what you assign to it is a mutable array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i know the big difference between mutable and something that is not mutable. I have more to study for ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `titles` array contains `NSString` objects. So you can't call it like:

```
NSMutableArray *current = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[current removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Also you have an `NSArray`, it's immutable so you should use `NSMutableArray` instead (When you declare it as NSMutableArray, you should also ensure that the assigning array is also a NSMutableArray). Or instead of these you can fix it using:

```
NSMutableArray *current = [self.titles mutableCopy];
[current removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.titles = [current copy];
```

Comment: It would probable make sense to make `self.titles` an `NSMutableArray` (and to move the property to the private class extension).

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, you are correct. It is better than calling mutableCopy and copy each time